# How to fit an background image with Tailwindcss?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an image with a height of 300px and a width of 1600px. I want to use it as a background image in a div element.

But when I make the height of the div more than 300, it does cover the width but at the top, there remains an empty space.

I want the background image to cover the entire div both in height and width.

This is the result when the height is 450 px.
[image: This is the result when the height is 450px]

I am using tailwindcss and next.js

```
<div className="bg-[url('/image.jpg')] w-full h-[250px] bg-center-bottom bg-no-repeat bg-cover mb-8 md:bg-cover md:h-[350px]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, but it is the same answer as the previous one and (md:bg-cover) breakpoints are not needed.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="bg-[url('https://plchldr.co/i/1600x300?&bg=67229f&fc=f8f8f8&text=1600x300')] w-full h-[250px] bg-cover bg-center bg-no-repeat mb-8 md:h-[350px]"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try it out. I see you have used bg-center-bottom  and bg-center at the same time. But in the code editor, using same two styles shows an error in the problems section saying 'bg-center' uses the same styles as 'bg-bottom'. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Sorry. The solution you provided doesn't work either. It is the same as before. When the div reaches more than 300 px, the height of the image, the result is the same as the screenshot provided in the question.

Comment: As you can see it works (my local pc with next.js and tailwind). I think it is a config problem on your side or layout. Can you provide more information? [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It was in the config file. `   backgroundSize: {
      '90%': '90%',
      '100%': '100%',
    },` This is the reason bg-cover didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Cover
Use bg-cover to scale the background image until it fills the background layer.

```
<div class="bg-cover bg-center ..." style="background-image: url(...)"></div>
```

Comment: I did use bg-cover both in all and md breakpoints. But it doesn't work

Comment: How its not working can you share in the question? Like any screenshot or any tailwind play link?

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot